# Why the tube is flat in the center

Tags: bevel

With the plane added delete 1 edge and bevel the side corner and with the bevel circle i have bevel it. Problem it bevel but the center part is flat and the both end are rounded like a tube. I have set the radius 1 yet to cant find the result to be fully tube.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is because the curve has an non homogeneous scale. Apply its scale (ctrl+A then scale)

Comment: Thats perfect what need plz added as a answer

Comment: Just a additional question how the scale is disturb. I have just taken the plane and bevel the corners.

Comment: What is this additional question? I don't get it? Anyway I've just noted that the scale was wrong, but I don't know how you obtained that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The bevel object, used to bevel a curve, follows the curve's scale.

So if the scale of the curve is not homogeneous, the bevel object will appear unevenly scaled itself. To correct that, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> then 'scale' to keep the shape of the curve, and set all scaled directions equal to 1.

[image]